# Prolog 99 Problems: Run-length encoding of a list

Tags: prolog

I am not sure how the Program will end up with L2

```
encode(L1,L2) :-
   pack(L1,L),
   transform(L,L2).

L2= [[2, a], [3, b], [2, c]]

L1=[a,a,b,b,b,c,c].
 using pack I would get 

L=[[a,a],[b,b,b],[c,c]].


%1.rule: 
transform([],[]).
%2.rule:
transform([[X|Xs]|Ys],[[N,X]|Zs]) :-
   length([X|Xs],N),
   transform(Ys,Zs).
```

so assume the program will go like this.

it will first check the fist rule which is not true and move on to the second rule.

```
transform([[a|[a]]|[[b,b,b],[c,c]]],[[N|a]|Zs]) :-
   length([a|[a]],2), transform([[b,b,b],[c,c]],Zs).
transform([[b|[b,b]]|[c,c],[[2|b]|Zs]) :-
   length([b|[b,b]],3), transform([c,c],Zs).
transform([[c|[c]]|[]],[[3|b]|Zs]) :-
   length([c|[c]],3), transform([],Zs).
```

and then I don't really get how the program proceeds, I tried to understand it enabling the trace functionality of Prolog, but still I cannot grasp it.

Comment: Of interest: RosettaCode - Prolog - [RLE](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Prolog)

Comment: `[a,a]` isn't `[a|a]`, but rather `[a|[a]]`. The tail is a list, not a simple atom. Similarly, `[b,b,b]` would  be `[b|[b,b]]`. You would get `transform([[a,a],[b,b,b],[c,c]], [[N,a]|Zs])` which leads to `length([a,a], N), transform([[b,b,b],[c,c]], Zs).` giving `N = 2`. Then you get `transform([b|[b,b]], [[N,b]|Zs])` leading to `length([b,b,b], N), transform([[c,c]], Zs).` leading to `N = 3`, etc. `transform([], Zs)` succeeds with `Zs = []` finishing the recursive process.

Comment: thank you for the hint, I have corrected it. So basically it determines first the value for N and then unifies it, so when it calls transform recursively N is unbound again?

Comment: Yes, on the recursive call, that is essentially a "new" `N`.